# How to register the client side added data for postback validation on server side?

Tags: asp.net, events, validation, callback

If I add Items to a Select element at the client side and then submit the form, I get the following error:-

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

I do not want to disable the EventValidation. How can I register the data added at the client side to a particular element for postback validation at server side ?

I know the `RegisterForEventValidation` method is there, but I have never used it and even I don't understand from the msdn.

If anyone has ever done this, can you please share a sample code with brief explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I know all the values in advance that can be added to the ListBox at the Client side, so fortunately, there is a solution for this:-

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(lstBox.UniqueID, "ListItemValue 
 that can be added at client side");
 base.Render(writer);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I never had good luck with this, I found it much easier to subclass the necessary control just in that particular case in order to avoid ASP.NET attempting to validate it.  This is better than turning of validation for the page as everything but that control will still be validated as always.  I'm assuming in your case you're using a server side HtmlSelect (same can be done with DropDownList).  Here is one option:

```
public class NoEventValdationHtmlSelect : HtmlSelect
{
}
```

You'll have to retrieve the selected value via Request.Form[UniqueNameOfControl] since SelectedIndex/Value/Item will be null on the server side.

Comment: +1 for you reply. But I found the answer for my question that it is not entirely possible, but if I know the values that are going to be added on the client side in advance, then I can register those values to be valid post data for that control using **Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation**. Thanks!